Bootstrapping the average derivative estimator
Let $f(x)=\mathbb E[Y\mathop | X=x]$ be the regression function, and $\hat {f}(x)$ be its estimate (using kernel regression, for example). The average derivative estimator (Härdle and Stoker, 1989; Rilstone, 1991; Rodríguez and Shelton, 2013) is defined by
$$
\hat\mu_X=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n{\hat {f^{\prime}}}(X_i)
$$
Note that $\hat \mu_X$ is a consistent estimator of $\mathbb E[f'(X)]$. Similarly, we can define the estimator for higher-order derivatives $\mathbb E[f^{(n)}(X)]$:
$$
\hat\mu_X^{(m)}=\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n\hat f^{(n)}(X_i)
$$
Now I want to do hypothesis testing on the average derivatives. Specifically. I want to test
$$
H_0:\mathbb E[f'(X)]=0
$$
and
$$
H_0':\mathbb E[f''(X)]=0.
$$
I use a bootstrap procedure as follows: Denote the bootstrapped samples as $x_1,\cdots,x_B$, each of them is a vector of a certain size (say $k$), refit the model on the bootstrapped data, calculate the t-statistic of derivatives (demeaned by subtracting $\hat\mu_X$), and then the $p$-value is given by the proportion of bootstrapped $t$-statistics that are larger than the $t$-statistic calculated from the whole sample. It is similar to the bootstrap test for the mean of a random variable. (Here's some slides, for reference)

Now I want to know, is this test valid (I've already implemented it in R)? Should I refit the model for each bootstrapped sample?
